# Can an alias be defined with the same name as parent template class in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, language-lawyer, using

In following example struct `Derived<T>` inherits from `Base<T>` and defines an alias to its parent with the name `Base`:

```
template <class T>
struct Base {
    Base(int) {}
};

template <class T>
struct Derived : Base<T> {
    using Base = Base<T>;
    Derived() : Base(1) {}
};

int main() {
    Derived<char> x;
}
```

Clang permits this code, but GCC prints the error:

```
error: declaration of 'using Base = struct Base<T>' changes meaning of 'Base' [-fpermissive]
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/srMT7hdWr

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: Just a note, apart from actually specifying the base, `Base` name is already injected into `Derived` scope, `Derived<char>::Base y{1};` will work even without the alias (for public inheritance ofc).